# hline doesn't work as expected in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

How come the code below works:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)
price = (ticker == "EURUSD" ? 1.1600 : 1.1500)
hline(1.1500, title='Pi', color=blue, linestyle=dotted, linewidth=2)
plot(price)
```

But this doesn't:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)
price = (ticker == "EURUSD" ? 1.1600 : 1.1500)
hline(price, title='Pi', color=blue, linestyle=dotted, linewidth=2)
plot(price)
```

Only difference is using a variable for the hline parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the idea of `hline()` is to have a horizontal line at a **fixed** price. If you use a ***variable*** for the `price` parameter, then it is **not** "*fixed*" anymore. Because a variable can have a different value during run-time. Hence, you cannot use variables.

Comment: This answer is close enough. But the real problem seem to be how pine-script is crippled to only use (vector) series for *variables*. Therefore `hline()` is unhappy to see a series instead of a single value.

Comment: hline() in tradingview is suck. That's not good enough to provide a tool to annotate the chart as developer wants.

Comment: So what is the workaround to plotting a horizontal line at a variable price level? Or maybe there is a way to pass a variable as a constant to the function?

Comment: You can workaround this by creating a line with enabled extend, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Workaround

```
line hLine = line.new(
      x1     = bar_index-1, 
      y1     = price,
      x2     = bar_index,
      y2     = price,
      xloc   = xloc.bar_index,
      color  = color.blue,
      extend = extend.both,
      style  = line.style_dotted,
      width  = 2)
line.delete(hLine[1])
```